# How do I replace text in rows by the respective columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to replace text "vegetables" in rows 1-5 entirely with the respective car make names in column A.

For example row 1 should find the word BMW and replace it with all words containing "vegetables" in the same row.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maeQC.jpg)

Could someone tell me the VBA code for this? i need to get something done for my work and it would take hours to replace every cell manually.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3T6a2Q2.jpg


sorry i forgot to add the image.

Comment: Replace in current cell would require VBA, or, manually select row by row and use CTRL-H. Alternatively, you may be able to figure out a formula and basically replicate your data further to the right or in another sheet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added an image so you could follow my thoughts

Comment: Always include what you have tried so far. If you're writing VBA code, post what you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You won't need much time for this task.
In your big screenshot does the data end up in column N? So, go to cell P1 and write the formula

`=SUBSTITUTE(C1;"vegatables";$A1)`

Now stretch this down to the end of the list. Then stretch it to the right (the entire column), far enough to process all the data. Copy the resulting and paste as values over the original cells.

Comment: thanks, it worked!